# pyspark dataframe.write.saveAsTable memory errors

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I'm looping through a set of csv files containing `file_id, mimetype, file_data` and using `Databricks` spark-csv to create a DataFrame.  Then I want to write that dataframe to a Parquet Hive table.  Each csv file is approximately 400MB and contains 1 to n rows based on the size of the `file_data` column which contains a binary file (ppts, pdfs, etc.).  I'm getting memory errors and wonder if there is a better way or how I might read or write each DataFrame row separately. I'm running pyspark through Jupyter on Cloudera CDH5.5.1 on a 13 node cluster.

```
for f in files:
   fullpath = path + f
   df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
      .options(header='false', 'inferschema='false', nullValue='NULL', treatEmptyValuesAsNulls='true') \
      .load(fullpath), schema = customSchema)
   print df.count()
   df.write.format("parquet").mode("append").saveAsTable(tablename)
   print "done"
```

Comment: First of all you should add a df.cache() before df.count() to avoid reading in the entire dataset two times.

Comment: Also why is there a single quote before `inferSchema`, and why is there code after `.load(fullpath)`?

Comment: What kind of errors exactly? And what is n?  If single row is large (lets say multiple megabytes) then you need a lot of memory per executor thread. Not to mention that saving row binary files in this format is probably not the best idea.